# Problem with opaque image overlay IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, opacity

I'm having trouble setting an opaque overlay div over an image in IE7. Every other browser (note: IE6 and older haven't been tested) handle my code and markup well, but IE7 doesn't. The overlay is not opaque, and the underlying image is not shown.

Here is my markup.

```
    <li>
        <a href="/AquaTrade/designclub/index.php/cs/program/12-program/89-miloslav-cejka">
        <div style="background-image: url(http://10.0.0.3/AquaTrade/designclub/images/stories/program-ico/ikona-cejka-a-club.jpg);">
            <div class="catImg" style="opacity: 0.6; ">
                <!--img src="http://10.0.0.3/AquaTrade/designclub/images/stories/program-ico/ikona-cejka-a-club.jpg" alt="" /-->
            </div>
            <div class="catTitle"><span>Miloslav Čejka</span></div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

The opacity on div.catImg is set by jQuery fadeTo function, so in IE is it alpha-opacity
Following function set the opacity

```
function createCategories() {

    jQuery("#categories div.catImg").fadeTo(0,0.6);
    jQuery("#categories div.catImg").mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 0 );
    });
    jQuery("#categories div.catImg").mouseout(function() {
        jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 0.6 ); 
    });
    makeCategoriesPosition();
}
```

Comment: div can not be nested within element a. div is a block element and should not appear inside an anchor

Comment: should fix it with DOCTYPE html:) and what about when has the anchor set display: block?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `opacity` in IE css.

[see this article for more](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are nesting a div within a link. Its probably somehow not displaying as a block element because its inside the link tag.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated a sample for you with a correct model:

Css is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper 
    {
        position:absolute;
        }
    span 
    {
       display:block;
       background-color:black;
       opacity:0.6;
       filter:alpha(opacity=60);
       width:1024px;
       height:768px;
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
        }
</style>
```

jQuery is:

```
$(function () {

        $('a').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('span').fadeTo(0, 0);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('span').fadeTo(0, 0.6);
        });

    });
```

Html is:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <a href='go somwhere'>
        <span></span>
        <img src='Chrysanthemum.jpg' alt='A red flower' />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also I don't know if you have done this to make it easier for us to read. But never ever use inline css...it slows down your page and goes against separation of concern and good practice

Comment: the inline css comes from the code was copied from webkit inspector..its added by jquery..I hope so:)
right now I am rewriting the markup..I hope it will help

Comment: unfortunately not working..i will try exactly your code..It renders properly in IE7(IE9 switched to IE7) on Win7, but nasty in IE on XP..Interesting is that it's seems to be crumpled by javascript:)While loading it displays for tiny time properly and then..grr

so your code is indeed ok..I really hate this

Comment: http://cl.ly/1g1q1N1x0y1B0T1g1j38

this is how its looking now..the catImg element is the overlay